# TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds with tunnelblick

Tags: vpn

I wanted to connect to vpn and used ready configuration file provided by company I work at. I am using macOS and thus tunnelblick. But when I click on "connect" then I got stuck in "authorization":

```
2021-02-22 20:08:45.407794 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:53745
2021-02-22 20:08:45.445975 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'pid'
2021-02-22 20:08:45.446048 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'auth-retry interact'
2021-02-22 20:08:45.446088 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
2021-02-22 20:08:45.446109 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state'
2021-02-22 20:08:45.446142 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'bytecount 1'
2021-02-22 20:08:45.446819 *Tunnelblick: Established communication with OpenVPN
2021-02-22 20:08:45.459662 *Tunnelblick: >INFO:OpenVPN Management Interface Version 1 -- type 'help' for more info
2021-02-22 20:08:45.461317 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
2021-02-22 20:08:45.461564 NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
2021-02-22 20:08:45.484613 *Tunnelblick: Obtained passphrase from the Keychain
2021-02-22 20:08:45.485552 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'password [...]'
2021-02-22 20:08:45.488601 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
2021-02-22 20:08:45.488642 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
2021-02-22 20:08:45.488939 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1614006525,RESOLVE,,,,,,
2021-02-22 20:08:45.496536 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]109.107.200.210:1192
2021-02-22 20:08:45.496616 Socket Buffers: R=[786896->786896] S=[9216->9216]
2021-02-22 20:08:45.496635 UDP link local: (not bound)
2021-02-22 20:08:45.496650 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]109.107.200.210:1192
2021-02-22 20:08:45.496679 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1614006525,WAIT,,,,,,
2021-02-22 20:08:45.589736 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1614006525,AUTH,,,,,,
2021-02-22 20:08:45.589801 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]109.107.200.210:1192, sid=ccb6a360 722532cd
2021-02-22 20:09:45.121118 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
2021-02-22 20:09:45.121224 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
2021-02-22 20:09:45.121413 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
2021-02-22 20:09:45.121436 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1614006585,RECONNECTING,tls-error,,,,,
2021-02-22 20:09:45.145721 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
2021-02-22 20:09:45.145779 NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
2021-02-22 20:09:45.145880 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1614006585,RESOLVE,,,,,,
2021-02-22 20:09:45.147176 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]109.107.200.210:1192
2021-02-22 20:09:45.147225 Socket Buffers: R=[786896->786896] S=[9216->9216]
2021-02-22 20:09:45.147240 UDP link local: (not bound)
2021-02-22 20:09:45.147252 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]109.107.200.210:1192
2021-02-22 20:09:45.147270 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1614006585,WAIT,,,,,,
2021-02-22 20:09:45.147507 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
2021-02-22 20:09:45.244033 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1614006585,AUTH,,,,,,
2021-02-22 20:09:45.244138 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]109.107.200.210:1192, sid=1ea09cc1 79075a36
```

the question is how did I do incorrectly and is it possible to track the issue?